# Question about Website Shortcuts on iOS 15

Tags: ios, shortcut

First post.. I work at uhaul and there is a separate website employees use to lookup contracts and other stuff like that it’s referred to as .net in my post.

I have an iPhone XR with iOS 15 and I've been playing around with Shortcuts and I'm a noob so I'm stuck.. I basically want to make a shortcut that:

- pulls up the url for equipment search on .net
- Add the **action** "choose from menu"
  - have 3 options
  - search by equipment #
  - search by contract #
  - search by phone #
- paste the most recent number from my clipboard into the appropriate text field
- select Go

I've got it running. It takes me to the website fine, I log in fine. The 3 options pop up (equipment/contract/phone #s) Then I get stuck..
I want to make it paste most recent item from my clipboard into the text field I chose from the 3 options in my menu.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I don’t believe what you are wanting to achieve is currently possible in Shortcuts. You can’t interact with Safari like that using Shortcuts (currently).Does your company have an iOS app? Can manipulating the url accomplish what you need?

Comment: We currently do not have an app… iOS 15 has new features like “run JavaScript on Safari” “get details of safari webpage” “get contents of webpage(input: URL > result: rich text) stuff like that.. would that help me out?

Comment: If you know how to use Developer mode in Safari, you might be able to extract the GET/POST requests the site sends to the server once one of the three options is selected. Then you can use Shortcuts to have the user selection one of the three options locally and just call the appropriate URL.